# Spring Many To Many not saved on form submit

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class LabelGroup{
    transient Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LabelGroup.class);

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "labelGroup", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Token> tokens;

    public List<Token> getTokens() {
        return tokens;
    }

    public void setTokens(List<Token> tokens) {
        for (Token t: tokens){
            this.addToken(t);
        }
    }

    public void addToken(Token token){
        token.setLabelGroup(this);
        tokens.add(token);
    }


    @Override
    public void copy(LabelGroup other) {
        setName(other.getName());
        setBody(other.getBody());
    }

    @Override
    public String getEditURL() {
        return CrudEntityController.getEitURL(CrudEntityController.LABEL_GROUP_PREFIX).replace("{id}",this.getId()+"");
    }

    public LabelGroup() {
        tokens = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Token {
    @Column(nullable = false,name = "token_key")
    String key;
    @Column(nullable = false,name = "token_value")
    String value;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    LabelGroup labelGroup;

    public Token() {
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public LabelGroup getLabelGroup() {
        return labelGroup;
    }

    public void setLabelGroup(LabelGroup labelGroup) {
        this.labelGroup = labelGroup;
    }
}
```

they also have IDs but left them out here...

I have this form for editing/creating label groups:

```
<form th:action="@{__${url}__}" method="post" th:object="${newGroup}">
    ...
    <th:block th:each="token, iter: ${newEntity.getTokens()}">
         <input type="text" th:field="*{tokens[__${iter.index}__].key}">
         <input type="text" th:field="*{tokens[__${iter.index}__].value}">
    </th:block>
</form>
```

When I try to create a new entity however when I submit the form and I log the tokens list, I can see the new tokens created but in the database the column label_group_id has no value.

```
@PostMapping(NEW_URL)
public String newEntitySave(@Valid @ModelAttribute("newEntity") LabelGroup entity, BindingResult result, Model model){
    checkPermissionByType(NEW_URL);

    boolean valid;

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        valid = false;
    }else {
        valid = validateNewEntity(entity,result);
    }

    if(valid){

        getRepository().save(entity);
        
        return getRedirectIndex();
    }else{
        setupModelForEntityForm(null,model,null);
        return FORM_TEMPLATE;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

It seems to me that spring does not call setters but sets the values directly. Is this right? If so, the `labelGroup` of the tokens is not set. But really is the only way around this is iterating the tokens and setting the value manually before the entity save?

Comment: Your IDs autogenerated or submitted by form?

Comment: They are autogenerated